# golang type assertion, what the different between interface{}(pointer) and interface{}(object)?

Tags: pointers, go, type-assertion

Why do I assign a value to a type assertion result where the interface is assigned by a pointer, and it comes to a "cannot assign" error when I do it to a interface which is assigned by a struct object?

Here's my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Person interface {
    SayHi()
}

type Student struct {
    id int
    name string
}

func (s Student) SayHi() {
    fmt.Println("hi, i am", s.name, " my id is:", s.id)
}

func main() {
    p1 := Person(&Student{id: 123, name: "William"})
    p1.SayHi()      // ok
    p1.(*Student).SayHi()  // ok here
    p1.(*Student).id = 456 // ok here
    p2 := Person(Student{id: 123, name: "William"})
    p2.SayHi()         //ok 
    p2.(Student).SayHi()  // ok here
    p2.(Student).id = 456 // error here and why?
    fmt.Println("p1:", p1, " p2:", p2)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/dwkvLzng_n

Comment: `p2.(Student)` produces a kind of temporary object (copy) which immediately gets disposed. What is the purpose of assignment to it?

Comment: I am a new bee at golang, I'm trying to get known of some intrinsic about the language better

Comment: If you want to gain insight in Go: Stop trying inheritance-type design. Go doesn't support this and you'll hurt yourself.

Comment: @Volker It's just a basic interface implementation. what do you mean by `inheritance-type design` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the result of `value.(typeName)` is a new (copy) value with the static type `typeName`.

`p2.(Student).id=456` will create a temporary `Student` value, any modifications  of that value would be discarded. So the language just disallows this mistake.